# Android 4.0+ devices says cannot generate texture from bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

I have list view with in the adapter i am doing this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = gotBitmap;
        Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height, true);
        Shader mShader = new BitmapShader(bm, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
```

Only in Android devices with 4.0+ it gives me this error "cannot generate texture from bitmap "

In Google Developer Console under optimization tips its given that "Target and minimum Android versions support tablets"

So i have added

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

After adding this i am getting this error,if i remove this and run the app, the app works fine.

How to solve this issue? can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I have this error because bitmap file is corrupted. When acceleration is off then imageView is transparent.